# Can I access an ESE database that is already in use?

Tags: extensible-storage-engine

The windows ESE engine API call JetAttachDatabase have a readonly option. Can I use this to mount a database that is already mounted by another process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is almost certainly "no". ESENT databases are single-process only, unless all processes are using the database read-only. The other process has probably attached the database read-write so you won't be able to.